# Create a data column in an R dataframe based on a sequential comparison

Tags: r, loops

I am having an issue trying to generate values based off of a sequential conditional comparison from values in another column of a data frame.

Here are example Data:

```
ID  Tracked

1   Yes
1   Yes    
1   No    
1   No    
1   Yes    
1   Yes   
2   Yes    
2   No    
2   No    
2   Yes    
2   Yes    
2   Yes    
2   No    
2   Yes
```

What I would like is to add a third column based off of whether ID has at least a previous and successive Yes like this.

```
ID  Tracked Seq

1   Yes     NA    
1   Yes     1    
1   No      0    
1   No      0    
1   Yes     0    
1   Yes     1    
2   Yes     NA    
2   No      0    
2   No      0    
2   Yes     0    
2   Yes     1    
2   Yes     1    
2   No      0    
2   Yes     0
```

Many thanks for all your help.  I have tried numerous things and can not seem to come up with simple code but it is looking like I will need to construct a nested for loop.

The latest for loop I have tried (without looping over per ID yet as a test) is not working, just returning all zeros.

```
for (i in length(Data)){
   Data$Seq[i+1] <- ifelse(Data$Tracked[i]==Data$Tracked[i+1], 1, 0)
}
```

And the solution that works with the help of @parksw3

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
    df$Seq[1] <- NA
    df$Seq[i+1] <- 
    ifelse(df$Tracked[i]==df$Tracked[i+1], 1, 0) *
    ifelse(df$ID[i] == df$ID[i+1], 1, NA)
}
```

Comment: @m0h3n I think he means row right above by previous and successive. That's what his code seems to suggest anyways...

Comment: @m0h3n Yes that is exactly what I was getting at with the data.  Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want to do.

```
df <- read.table(
    text = "
    ID  Tracked

    1   Yes
    1   Yes
    1   No
    1   No
    1   Yes
    1   Yes
    2   Yes
    2   No
    2   No
    2   Yes
    2   Yes
    2   Yes
    2   No
    2   Yes",
    header = TRUE
)
```

`tmp` gives you a `TRUE/FALSE` vector that tells you whether the answer is yes or not. `tmp2` gives you a `TRUE/FALSE` vector that tells you whether the previous answer is yes or not, by adding `NA` to the beginning and removing the last element. Multiplying two will return `1` if both the previous and the current answers are yes and `0` otherwise.

```
dftmp <- aggregate(.~ID, df,
    FUN = function(x){
        tmp <- x == 2 ## If you want to use "Yes" instead, replace df with lapply(df, as.character) and replace 2 with "Yes"
        tmp2 <- c(NA, tmp[-length(tmp)])
        tmp * tmp2
    })

df$Seq <- unlist(dftmp[,-1])
```

Result:

```
print(df)
##    ID Tracked Seq
## 1   1     Yes  NA
## 2   1     Yes   1
## 3   1      No   0
## 4   1      No   0
## 5   1     Yes   0
## 6   1     Yes   1
## 7   2     Yes  NA
## 8   2      No   0
## 9   2      No   0
## 10  2     Yes   0
## 11  2     Yes   1
## 12  2     Yes   1
## 13  2      No   0
## 14  2     Yes   0
```

Also, to fix your code, it's somewhat sloppy but this should work:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
    df$Seq[i+1] <- 
        ifelse(df$Tracked[i]==df$Tracked[i+1], 1, 0) *
        ifelse(df$ID[i] == df$ID[i+1], 1, NA)
}
```

Comment: You might want to replace `lapply(df, as.character)` with just `df` and say `x==2` instead. So you can skip that.

Comment: I don't mind in this case but FYI, normally any suggested improvement by other users are referenced here in SO.

Comment: @m0h3n Got it. I fixed the code. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @parksw3 Thank you a bunch.  The for loop worked great.  I did get the error:

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PreTrack", value = c(NA, 1)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 20793

Comment: But I solved that easily by adding in the following to the for loop to fill that first value:

for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
    df$Seq[i+1] <- 
        ifelse(df$Tracked[i]==df$Tracked[i+1], 1, 0) *
        ifelse(df$ID[i] == df$ID[i+1], 1, NA)
}

Comment: Sorry, all first time user of this forum so I need to learn how to set up my data examples properly and realize I need to hit shift-return in the comments, not RETURN!  You can delete the previous comments above I have them summarized here:

@parksw3 Thank you a bunch. The for loop worked great. I did get the error:

"Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "PreTrack", value = c(NA, 1)) : replacement has 2 rows, data has 20793"

But I solved that easily by adding in the following to the for loop to fill that first value:

Data$seq[1] <- NA